# Internal server error ajax submission

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have a function that triggers on a button click that passes the following argument: `insertSongPlay(newSong.songID);` when I console.log the `newSong.songID` I see a value of 90, which is desired.

This function is called here which runs an ajax call:

```
function insertSongPlay(songID)

{
    $.ajax
    ({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "/Album/InsertSongPlay/",
        data: JSON.stringify({ "songID": songID }),
        success: function(data)
        {

            console.log("submitted");
            console.log(songID);
            //TODO: Indicate Success
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            //TODO: Indicate Error
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
```

Here is the corresponding ajax url found in my AlbumController:

```
public JsonResult InsertSongPlay(int songID)
{
    try
    {
        EntityDataAccess.InsertSongPlay(songID);
        return Json(true);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        return Json(ex);
    }
}
```

Then in my `EntityDataAccess.cs` the following is run from the `InsertSongPlay` entity data access:

```
public static SongPlayDaily InsertSongPlay(int songID)
{
    using(var Context = GetContext())
    {
        var currentSongPlay = Context.SongPlayDailies.FirstOrDefault(x => x.SongID == songID && x.PlayDate == DateTime.Now.Date);
        if (currentSongPlay != null)
            currentSongPlay.NumberOfPlays++;
        else
        {
            currentSongPlay = new SongPlayDaily();
            currentSongPlay.SongID = songID;
            currentSongPlay.PlayDate = DateTime.Now.Date;
            currentSongPlay.NumberOfPlays = 1;
            Context.SongPlayDailies.Add(currentSongPlay);
        }
        Context.SaveChanges();
        return currentSongPlay;
    }
}
```

However, my ajax call always throws an error and prints `Internal Server Error` to the console log. The Visual Studio debug mode indicates some sort of circular reference error. I'm not quite sure where I'm going wrong.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the error message exactly?

Comment: @epascarello my ajax response returns an error argument: `Internal Server Error`but in debug mode i see a bit more info: `A circular reference was detcted while serializing an object of type `System.Reflection.RuntimeModule`

Comment: Remove `return Json(ex)` - I guess that is what causes circular reference error. Then see what real error is thrown.

Comment: use `throw ` instead of using Json to see the actual error

Comment: @Niladri do not. Use `throw`, or simply remove `try/catch`.

Comment: yup i edited that part

Comment: @JordanLewallen can you post your SongPlayDaily model and dbcontext?May be one or more of your model properties are referencing t their parent properties

Comment: @Niladri @Evk I changed to catch as `throw ex`the new error is now: the speicied type member `Date` is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported`

Comment: @JordanLewallen seems the problem is with `PlayDate` . is it possible to use a string instead of date part?

Comment: Instead of this `x.PlayDate == DateTime.Now.Date`, save date in separate variable before query (`var today = DateTime.Now.Date`) and use that in query (`x.PlayDate == today`).

Comment: @Evk this fixed it! feel free to make this as an answer and I will accept, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we figured out in comments - there are multiple problems here. First,

```
return Json(ex);
```

Is a bad idea. That will inspect all properties of exception and try to serialize them, and all properties of those properties, to json. As you see, that is not going well, and also completely unnecessary. If you want to return error response to client - prepare it (use `ex.Message` for example). Plus, you don't want to return sensetive information (like stack trace) to your clients on every error.

Besides that - by doing `return Json()` on exception -  you violate HTTP conventions. `Json()` will return response with status code 200 OK. But in your case it's not really "ok" - so you should return another status code indicating error. If not that circular reference error - your code in ajax "error" handler would never has been triggered, even when there was really an error.

Easiest way to fix it is just remove try-catch completely and let framework handle that for you.

Second problem is

```
x.PlayDate == DateTime.Now.Date
```

filter in query. Entity Framework has problem with accessing `Date` property of `DateTime` objects and refuses to convert that into SQL query. You can either move that to another variable:

```
var today = DateTime.Now.Date;
Where(x => x.PlayDate == today)
```

or use `DbFunctions.TruncateTime`:

```
Where(x => x.PlayDate == DbFunctions.TruncateTime(DateTime.Now))
```

Note that those ways are not exactly equivalent. First will compare with exact date value, and second will use SQL `SYSDATETIME()` function. In this case that hardly matters though.

Answer (score 0):

Is it because you're missing the [HttpPost] attribute over your controller action?

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult InsertSongPlay(int songID)
{ 
    try
    {
        EntityDataAccess.InsertSongPlay(songID);
        return Json(true);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        return Json(ex);
    }   
}
```

Comment: unfortunately I don't think so, I added it with no change

Comment: It's most likely because the SongPlayDailies has a reference back to it's parent (SongPlayDaily) - you can make the field non-serializable to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

in post action you should use complex type for receive data from client.

try this

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult InsertSongPlay(SongModel songModel)
{ 
    try
    {
        EntityDataAccess.InsertSongPlay(songModel.songID);
        return Json(true);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        return Json(ex);
    }   
}

public class SongModel{
    public int songID {get;set}
}
```